# How to fix the correct value of span form?

Tags: javascript, function, otree

I have the following script calculating a simple sum. If sum exceed or is below 100 a display error is shown. Despite the error message the user is still allow to proceed to the following page. I would like that until the value is == 100 he can't move to the next page.

```
<table class="table-bordered" style=" width: 80%; margin-left: 10%;" >
  <tr style="background-color:#ffb380">
        <td scope="col"  colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quante Palline  per la Scelta 1 </td>
        <td scope="col"  colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quanti Palline per la Scelta 2 </td>
        <td scope="col"  colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Totale Palline Assegnate </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#ffe0cc">
        <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref1" type="number" name="pref1" min="0" max="100" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 25%"> </td>
        <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref2" type="number" name="pref2" min="0" max="100" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 25%"> </td>
        <td> <span  id="sum_token"  style="width: 50%; margin-left: 37%" ></span> su 100</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<div id="error" class="hide"><b>La somma dei gettoni deve essere 100</b></div>
<script>window.onload = init_sum_token();

function init_sum_token() {
  sum_token = document.getElementById("sum_token");
  pref1 = document.getElementById("pref1");
  pref2 = document.getElementById("pref2");

  document.querySelectorAll(".pref_input").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      sum_prefs =
        get_input_value(pref1) +
        get_input_value(pref2);
      let sum = parseFloat(sum_prefs);
      if (sum != 100) {
        sum = sum_prefs;
        document.getElementById("error").className = "show";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("error").className = "hide";
      }
      sum_token.innerHTML = sum;
    });
  });
}
function get_input_value(input) {
  if (input.value == "") {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return parseFloat(input.value);
  }
  if (input.value != 100) {
    return "error";
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

please compare the sum correctly in `get_input_value()` function it should be like this:

```
if (input.value > 100 || input.value < 100 ) {
    return "error";
  }
```

also correct it:

```
if (sum > 100 || sum < 100) {
        sum = sum_prefs;
....
```

Comment: @Haris Thank you very much for the correction. However, still if i input 0 and 99 i can submit the forms and proceed to the following page.